# Python 3: Unescape(?) a string

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have a string which is like the following:

```
>>> s = "aaa\\x20bbbb"
```

How can I "unescape" it, if that is even the right term for this, to a normal string?

I expect something like:

```
>>> s = "aaa bbb"
```

Workaround: I used replace but this works only on one kind of char at a time.

```
>>> s.replace("\\x20"," ")
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What do you *expect* to get as the result?

Comment: I searched for "unescape string" but the existing posts do not do exactly this.

Comment: The result should be a normal string with a space instead of the "escaped" space.

Comment: do you mean decoding ?

Comment: If you `print(s)`, you already *have* a string with a space…

Comment: I need a string with a space, not to print a string with a space.

Comment: You have a string literal which *represents a string with a space.* Once parsed by Python, it *is* a string with a space. `s` contains a string with a space. — Unless this isn't a representative code sample…

Comment: You want to decode the string, but you have double backslashes. Try replacing the double backslashes with single backslashes, and then use b"abc".decode("utf-8"). Example: `b"aaa\x20bbbb".decode("utf-8")` prints as expected `aaa bbbb`. Similarly, `print("aaa\x20bbbb")` prints `aaa bbbb`. Use a different encoding instead of "utf-8" if appropriate.

Comment: Its not a bytes so it cannot be decoded. Its already a str.

Comment: `"aaa\\x20bbbb".encode().decode('unicode-escape')`